# Setting a connection to an access database in VBA crashes excel

Tags: vba, excel, crash, adodb

This is the code I use to open a connection to an access database from excel.  It used to work for more than a year.

```
Set dbname = New ADODB.Connection
theconnection = "//xxx.sharepoint.com/sites" & Application.PathSeparator & TARGET_DB
With dbname
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Open theconnection
End With
```

By trial an error I've come to the conclusion that this line is causing the problem.

```
Set dbname= New ADODB.Connection
```

The problem began after an automatic update of my PC
My Excel version 2016 MSO (16.0.7726.1036) 32-bit

Please let me know if you have run also into this problem, and if you know any fix or workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- try to uncheck your 'ActiveX Data Objects' references and add them back:

**Tools - References**

or

- use object to define a database:

  ```
   Dim dbname As Object
   Set dbname = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  ```

or

if you create connection variable like this:

```
Dim con as New ADODB.Connection
```

change it to:

```
Dim con as ADODB.Connection
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints.  The problem is solved.  When I checked the References, I had Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.0 Library checked.  When I unchecked it, it disappeared.  Looks like during some of the office 365 upgrades, it was changed for version 6.1.  When I checked this version it began to work again. Thanks for your help again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
Dim dbname As Object
Set dbname = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

theconnection = "//xxx.sharepoint.com/sites" & Application.PathSeparator & TARGET_DB
With dbname
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Open theconnection
End With
```

I used like this , all code

```
Dim Rs As Object
Dim strConn As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "select * from [table] "
strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"


Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Rs.Open strSQL, strConn

If Not Rs.EOF Then
     With Ws
        .Range("a1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        For i = 0 To Rs.Fields.Count - 1
           .Cells(1, i + 1).Value = Rs.Fields(i).Name
        Next
        .Range("a" & 2).CopyFromRecordset Rs
    End With
End If
Rs.Close
Set Rs = Nothing
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't solve the problem.  It was the Microsoft ActiveX library upgrade that created this problem.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: @MarcinDramiński:  I modified my answer,  full code.